# Can Sikuli be used in Selenium scripts written in C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, sikuli

we are about to start using Selenium at my current project. I know theres some difficulty coding a test to handle a Win 10 security pop up at login. Ive read on this site that a good solution is to use Sikuli in Selenium. Can this be done if we are using C# as the language in Selenium?

Comment: How is this related to Java or JavaScript?

Comment: Because if perhaps Sikuli cannot be used w selenium / C# lang and only java and/or javascript. maybe a member here who uses javascript/ java and knows the answer to my question here buddy.

Comment: You ask about C#, not Java.

Comment: @ChrisShaw Technically you should be able to. JavaScript is one of the supported scripting languages. you should be able to achieve it using Javascript executor. in your case i.e c# its IJavaScriptExecutor

Comment: @KrunalPatel Thanks much for your reply. I appreciate it.

Comment: @JeffC I did search both here and on google and found no solid answer to the topic/ question. Im aware of the rules. Allow me to ask this: How is "How is this related to Java or JavaScript?" and "You ask about C#, not Java.:" telling me the rules?

Comment: You can avoid using Sikuli completely by passing the username/password in the URL. [This is an old blog post](http://aleetesting.blogspot.com/2011/10/selenium-webdriver-tips.html) but the basics are there. The answer is out there, you just have to look for it... sometimes it takes a while.

Comment: If you were aware of the rules (and followed them), you wouldn't have put 5 language tags on your question. From [ask], `...include a tag for the language, library, and specific API your question relates to.` Your question doesn't ask about all the other languages, only C#. The questions that EJoshuaS asked you were meant to point out, maybe a little too subtly, that you overtagged your question and that you should fix it. If you aren't sure what someone is asking you, then ask for clarification. You knew what he was asking because you came back with a sarcastic response instead of fixing it.

Comment: @JeffC Thanks for the info. I didnt craft the best search string so probably missed an answer two.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

For window based actions you can use AutoIT with selenium. AutoIT provides the functionality to handle desktop applications and alerts of windows.